# Get phone number from google map marker

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, infowindow, marker

I working with google map on android device , i am fetch information from markes , i am able to get marker title and maker snippet, but unable to get phone number information, please help me, thanks in advance.

```
package com.avion.mapdemo;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener {

```
// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
LatLng latLng;
GPSTracker gps;
Address adrs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        // Loading map

        initilizeMap();

        // my location...
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // room setting from 2(min) to 21 (max)..
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10.0f));

        // get my location address......

        myLocation();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // marker information tab clicked...........

    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

}

// method my location
private void myLocation() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // for logitude and latitude..........

    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        //double latitude = 40.71958;
        // double longitude = -74.09595;


        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),latitude
        // +"--"+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // for address..........
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                address + "" + city + "" + country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        Log.e("strite", address);
        Log.e("city", city);
        Log.e("country", country);
        // search string.....
        // String addr="Hotel "+address
        // +" "+city+" "+country;

        String addr = "Bar" + " " + city + " " + country;

        // call async task for load bars.....

        new GeocoderTask().execute(addr);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}

// An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        // Geocoder transforming a street address or other description of a
        // location
        // into a (latitude, longitude) coordinate.
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 10 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 10);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Bar found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Clears all the existing markers on the map
        googleMap.clear();

        // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
        for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {

            // address Strings describing a location
            adrs = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            // latLng class representing a pair of latitude and longitude
            // coordinates,

            latLng = new LatLng(adrs.getLatitude(), adrs.getLongitude());

            // latLng = new LatLng(40.71958,-74.09595);

            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s", adrs
                    .getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? adrs.getAddressLine(0)
                    : "", adrs.getCountryName());

            // markerOptions to add property to marker

            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(adrs.getAddressLine(0));
            markerOptions.snippet(adrs.getAddressLine(1) + ", "
                    + adrs.getAddressLine(2) + ", "
                    + adrs.getPhone());

            /*
             * getAddressLine(0) location name .
             * getAddressLine(1) local address .
             * getAddressLine(2) city,state .
             * getAddressLine(3) country .
             */
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Locate the first location
            if (i == 0)
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newLatLng(latLng));
        }
        // end of loop.....
    }
}

// on marker info tab click..
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    Toast.makeText(this, marker.getTitle() + "--" + marker.getSnippet(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

Comment: show me your code how to get information?

Comment: in last i hav to add phone number

Comment: any help full code or website link???

Comment: please post your code where you get this information? i mean any `Custom Window` or `Marker Click`.

Comment: please check the code...

Comment: ok fine . now tell me you got Snippet and title when you click in window?

Comment: ye i got that information

Comment: but my requirment is to fetch phone number from marker?

Comment: how can i fetch phone numbre from marker?

Answer (score 1):

You should `split` your `Snippet` `Marker` text and extract all the details.

see below

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

String[] str2 = marker.getSnippet().split(",");
String Addressline1=str2[0]; //Addressline 1
String Addressline2=str2[1]; //Addressline 2
String phone=str2[2]; //Phone

Toast.makeText(this, marker.getTitle() + "--" + marker.getSnippet()+"-- "+phone,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: no friend , it just showing some part of address, is their is any inbuild function?

Comment: @user3395433 it's because you have to `concat` your String using `, with one space`. get it what i am talk in about? carefully check it in your code. you must contcat using `single ,(comma)` no space/

Comment: no frd, i tried that also, problem is my concated string also dnt have mobile number, so their is nothing to deal with concatnation